# How do I properly use GradientTape to make a custom loss function in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm fairly new to TensorFlow (especially customization beyond the built-in losses/training/etc), and I'm having trouble implementing a custom loss function for a problem I'm trying to solve for fun. I've written a simple simulation of an idealized glider in two dimensions, and I want to train a neural network to fly it as far as it can. The model's input is an array containing the state variables (position, pitch, and their derivatives), and the desired output is a control variable that changes the pitch (essentially the angle of the simulated [elevator flaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_(aeronautics))). To achieve the training I want, the loss function simulates a flight, with the model providing control, and returns the negative of the distance traveled. However, when I try to train the model, the calculated gradients turn up empty. What am I doing wrong, and am I approaching this problem the right way?

My code:

```
def fall(control_model):
    #initialize physics constants and state variables
    dt, g = 1/25, 9.805
    x, y, theta = 0, 100, np.radians(-15)
    vx, vy, vtheta = 0, 0, 0

    while y > 0: #for each time step until we hit the ground:
        #preliminary calculations for aerodynamics
        vsq, vang, aoa = vx*vx + vy*vy, np.arctan2(vy, vx), theta - vang
        while aoa <= -np.pi:
            aoa += 2*np.pi
        while aoa > np.pi:
            aoa -= 2*np.pi
        aero, aeroang = 1*vsq*np.square(np.sin(aoa)), aoa%np.pi + np.pi/2 + vang

        #make an array of state variables and pass it to the model to get the control variable c
        state = np.asarray([[x/100, y/100, theta/np.pi, vx/10, vy/10, vtheta/np.pi]], dtype = np.float32)
        c = control_model(state).numpy()[0][0]

        #integrate acceleration into speed into position
        vx += aero*np.cos(aeroang)*dt
        vy += (aero*np.sin(aeroang) - g)*dt
        vtheta += (
                0.1*vsq*np.cos(aoa)*0.5*np.sin(2*np.radians(c)) #control term
                -0.05*vsq*np.square(np.sin(aoa))*np.sign(aoa) #angle of attack tends to zero
                -0.8*vtheta)*dt #damping
        x += vx*dt
        y += vy*dt
        theta += vtheta*dt
    return -x #the loss is the negative of distance traveled

control = tf.keras.Sequential() #simple model for MWE
control.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation = "relu", input_shape = (6,)))
control.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss2 = tf.Variable(fall(control))
gradients = tape.gradient(loss2, control.trainable_variables)
print(gradients) #prints [None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call g.watch for each of these variables:
Refer: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape

```
input_images_tensor = tf.constant(input_images_numpy)
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(input_images_tensor)
    output_tensor = model(input_images_tensor)

gradients = g.gradient(output_tensor, input_images_tensor)
```